# Postgresql PIVOT

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I'm pretty new in the world of sql queries and would appreciate help with pivoting.
I have a table similar to this one:

[image: Table 1]

That I want to turn into this:

[image: Table 2]

I bet it is a pretty straightforward process but still any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c47fa/1)

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (Description varchar(255), Label varchar(255),Val varchar(255));
INSERT INTO MyTable (Description,Label,Val) VALUES ('Name1','Location','Europe')
,('Name1','Depth','1200'),('Name1','Date','24.2.2011'),('Name2','Location','Australia')
,('Name2','Depth','3233'),('Name2','Date','1.1.1999'),('Name3','Location','Africa')
,('Name3','Depth','1323'),('Name3','Date','15.2.2018')
```

**Query 1**:

```
with CTE AS (select *,
(CASE WHEN Label='Location' THEN Val  END) AS Location,
(CASE WHEN Label = 'Depth' THEN Val END) AS Depth,
(CASE WHEN Label='Date' THEN Val END) AS Dates,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Label,Val Order By Description) as rn
from MyTable
group by Label,Description,Val              )

select c.Description
,max(c.Location) AS Location
,max(c.Depth) AS Depth
,max(c.Dates) AS Dates
from cte c
where rn=1
group by c.Description 
order by c.Description
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c47fa/1/0)**:

```
| description |  location | depth |     dates |
|-------------|-----------|-------|-----------|
|       Name1 |    Europe |  1200 | 24.2.2011 |
|       Name2 | Australia |  3233 |  1.1.1999 |
|       Name3 |    Africa |  1323 | 15.2.2018 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result using [tablefunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html) & [crosstab()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html#id-1.11.7.47.4.5) without complexity. For that, you need to create the below extension

`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;`

and a single select statement will do the trick,

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab('SELECT Description, Label, Val
    FROM   bar
    ORDER  BY 1'
    ) AS ct("Description" text, "Location" text, "Depth" text, "Date" text);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/MAEA97860)</kbd>

Comment: This method is clever, but in my experience this might consume too much DB session memory when processing a lot of result rows (i.e. too many `Description` output) before PGSQL 14. 

Answer (score 0):

A trick is to aggregate into a json(b) field, and unpack that. As with any EAV, You still need to take care of the correct data types.

---

```
CREATE table eav
        ( description text
        , label text
        , value text
        );

INSERT INTO eav(description, label, value) VALUES
 ( 'name1' , 'location' , 'Europe') , ( 'name1' , 'depth' , '1200') , ( 'name1' , 'date' , '24.2.2011')
 , ( 'name2' , 'location' , 'Australia') , ( 'name2' , 'depth' , '3233') , ( 'name2' , 'date' , '1.1.1999')
 , ( 'name3' , 'location' , 'Africa') , ( 'name3' , 'depth' , '1323') , ( 'name3' , 'date' , '12.5.2018')
        ;

SELECT xx.description
        , xx.ja->>'location' AS location
        , (xx.ja->>'depth')::integer AS depth
        , to_date(xx.ja->>'date', 'dd.m.yyyy') AS zdate
FROM    (       -- Aggregate EAV into json
        SELECT e.description
        , json_object_agg( e.label, e.value) AS ja
        FROM eav e
        GROUP BY 1
        ) xx
        ;
```

---

Result:

---

```
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 9
 description | location  | depth |   zdate    
-------------+-----------+-------+------------
 name3       | Africa    |  1323 | 2018-05-12
 name2       | Australia |  3233 | 1999-01-01
 name1       | Europe    |  1200 | 2011-02-24
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional aggregation without using suq-query :

```
select description, 
       max(value) filter (where label = 'location') as location,
       max(value) filter (where label = 'depth') as depth,
       max(value) filter (where label = 'zdate') as zdate
from table t
group by description;
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly improved version based on json feature mentioned by [wildplasser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61954765/7694704), utilizing one more json function `json_to_record()` / `jsonb_to_record()`.

```sql
CREATE table eav(
 description text,
 label text,
 value text
);

INSERT INTO eav(description, label, value) VALUES
 ( 'name1' , 'location' , 'Europe') ,
 ( 'name1' , 'depth' , '1200') ,
 ( 'name1' , 'date' , '24.2.2011') ,
 ( 'name2' , 'location' , 'Australia') ,
 ( 'name2' , 'depth' , '3233') ,
 ( 'name2' , 'date' , '1.1.1999') ,
 ( 'name3' , 'location' , 'Africa') ,
 ( 'name3' , 'depth' , '1323') ,
 ( 'name3' , 'date' , '12.5.2018') ;

with jagg as (
    select description,
    jsonb_object_agg(label, value) as jsn
    from eav
    group by description)
select
    jagg.description,
    jrcd.*
from jagg
cross join jsonb_to_record(jagg.jsn)
as jrcd (
    location text,
    depth numeric,
    date timestamp);
```

Output result

```js
 description | location  | depth |        date
-------------+-----------+-------+---------------------
 name3       | Africa    |  1323 | 2018-05-12 00:00:00
 name2       | Australia |  3233 | 1999-01-01 00:00:00
 name1       | Europe    |  1200 | 2011-02-24 00:00:00
(3 rows)
```

In this trick, your column definitions (including datatype mappings) are set in `jrcd`, which is more convenient than JSON operators.